# Elastic jar dependencies with Gradle

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, groovy

I'm trying to upgrade my elastic search and Jest from 2.x to 5.x, which is a large jump. I am running into some dependency issues. When I piped the tree to a file and looked for the 2.4.4 elastic jar (which seems to be the main problem) anywhere, I am getting this:

`|    +--- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.4.2 -> 2.4.4`

So somewhere the 2.4 is still being picked up and no matter what version you give it, it always uses 2.4. I have it pointing to the 5.4.2 jar in my gradle file and all references I find is pointing to the 5.4.2 jar.

I grep'd the package I have honed it down to with "2.4.4". I found the following:
`.idea/libraries/Gradle__org_elasticsearch_elasticsearch_2_4_4.xml`

Is there any reason this would be tied to the start up of IntelliJ? I'm throwing stuff at the wall here since I cannot seem to find why this jar is overriding any other version.

I have also blew away my gradle cache and rebuilt. 
Might be a fairly specific problem but if anyone has any ideas to toss out I'm all ears.

Comment: I recently had the same problem and could not be bothered to hunt it down.  I always had the impression, that gradle (or aether or whatever) would favour the higher version of transient deps.  To fix my problem i pinned the ES version directly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean 'pinned it directly'. I am building my own jar that takes in the elastic dependencies and importing it into another project via gradle

Comment: I have put a direct `compile` dependency to `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch` in the same version as my transport/client/whateveryouareusing in my Gradle file.

Comment: Yep I have done that as well, there is some other dependency throwing it back to ES version 2.4.4